# Access the volume button through my android app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android app which should be able to  identify when someone press the hardware volume up  button of the phone  ,  and give a notification saying "volume  up button has pressed".

**This is my  BroadcastReceiver class.**

```
package com.example.volumebut;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HardwareButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 KeyEvent e = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT); 
     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "volume up  button pressed." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

}





}
```

**This is my manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.volumebut"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.volumebut.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".HardwareButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Since I am new to android development I have no idea how  to implement  **MainActivity.java** file.

This is the  **MainActivity.java** file I have wrote so far. But it gives an error saying **"The method registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(HardwareButtonReceiver) is undefined for the type MainActivity"**

```
package com.example.volumebut;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    HardwareButtonReceiver receiver = new HardwareButtonReceiver();

    registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiver);

}




}
```

If you guys can help me to solve my problem I appreciate It much.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

go through above link you will get different key events

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
//          
            }
            else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
            {

            }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: ,Thank u. can u  tell me ,  where  must I put this code segment in my MainActivity.java file. Do I need to call to this method inside onCreate method? Please clarify it.

Comment: creat this method in you are activity ... it is activity method it will work

Answer (score 0):

You must add method `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` to your activity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xml_of_your_activity);
        HardwareButtonReceiver receiver = new HardwareButtonReceiver();
        registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private void registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(HardwareButtonReceiver receiver) {

    }
}
```

And then implement it of course.

Comment: @ Fox in socks , I did as u said. But then I get a run time error saying  "The Application VolumeBtn  (process com.example.volumebtn) has stopped unexpectedly.please try again. " Sometimes the way I have implemented onCreate method may wrong. So , can u propose an alternative way to implement the onCreate method except the way I have implemented it.

Comment: @hasitha1990 at least you need to call super method: `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and then set content view: `setContentView(R.layout.xml_of_your_activity);` So I recommend you read documentation(Java and Android) and try to develop simpler project to understand basics. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @ Fox in socks , Thanks I did as u said. Now app runs without any errors. But the problem is , it don't identify volume button pressing. Sometimes my logic may not be compatible to identify volume button pressing.

Comment: @hasitha1990 so it depends on your code. I don't know what goes worn. But you can add code of `rajahsekar` to your `activity` and it should work.